# My code generates the following error: TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python

```
import pygame
from random import*

def minas(n,bombas):
    tablero=crear_tablero(n)
    tablero=agregar_bombas(tablero,bombas)
    tablero=cambiar_tablero(tablero)
    return tablero


def crear_tablero(n):
    a=[]
    for i in range(n):
        a.append([0]*n)

    return a

def agregar_bombas(tablero,bombas):
    for i in range(bombas):
        es_bomba=False
        while not es_bomba:
            x=randint(0,len(tablero)-1)
            y=randint(0,len(tablero[0])-1)
            if tablero[x][y] !=9:
                tablero[x][y]=9
                es_bomba=True
    return tablero

def cambiar_tablero(tablero):
    for x in range(len(tablero)):
        for y in range(len(tablero[x])):
            if tablero[x][y]==9:
                tablero = abajoIzquierda(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = abajoDerecha(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = abajo(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = arribaIzquierda(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = arribaDerecha(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = arriba(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = Izquierda(tablero,x,y)
                tablero = Derecha(tablero,x,y)
    return tablero

def abajoIzquierda(tablero,x,y): 
    if (x+1)<len(tablero[x]) and (y-1)>=0:   #verifica la esquina derecha
        if tablero[x+1][y-1] !=9:  #no hace cambio si hay una bomba
            tablero[x+1][y-1]+=1
    return tablero

def abajoDerecha(tablero,x,y):
    if (x+1)<len(tablero[0]) and (y+1)<len(tablero):
        if tablero[x+1][y+1] !=9:
            tablero[x+1][y+1]+=1
    return tablero

def abajo(tablero,x,y):
    if (x+1)<len(tablero[0]):
        if tablero[x+1][y] !=9:
            tablero[x+1][y]+=1
    return tablero

def arribaIzquierda(tablero,x,y):
    if (x-1)>=0 and (y-1)>=0:
        if tablero[x-1][y-1] !=9:
            tablero[x-1][y-1]+=1
    return tablero

def arribaDerecha(tablero,x,y):
    if (x-1)>=0 and (y+1)<len(tablero):
        if tablero[x-1][y+1] !=9:
            tablero[x-1][y+1]+=1
    return tablero

def arriba(tablero,x,y):
    if (x-1)>=0:
        if tablero[x-1][y] !=9:
            tablero[x-1][y]+=1
    return tablero

def Derecha(tablero,x,y):
    if (y+1)<len(tablero):
        if tablero[x][y+1] !=9:
            tablero[x][y+1]+=1
    return tablero

def Izquierda(tablero,x,y):
    if (x+1)<len(tablero[x]) and (y-1)>=0:
        if tablero[x][y-1] !=9:
            tablero[x][y-1]+=1
    return tablero

def pr(tablero):
    for i in tablero:
        print(i)


class Board:
    def _init_(self,board):
        self.board=board
    def _repr_(self):
        pr(self.board)
        return "IS YOUR TABLE"

class Square:
    def _init_(self,x,y,w,h,board,ij):
        self.rect=pygame.rect.Rect(x,y,w,h)
        i,j=ij
        self.val=board[i][j]
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.visible=False
        self.flag=False

def restart(size,bombas):
    game=(size,bombas)



def open_game(size,bombas):
    square.visible=True
    i,j=square.x//40,square.y//40
    if i+1< len(lista):
        #chequeamos la casilla alrededor de la que estamos parados si esta visible o no
        #y si tiene bandera o no
        if lista[i+1][j].visible== False and lista[i+1][j].flag== False:
            lista[i+1][j].visible=True
            if lista[i+1][j].val==0:
                open_game(lista,lista[i+1][j])

        if j+1 < len(lista):
            if lista[i+1][j+1].visible==False and lista[i+1][j+1].flag==False:
                lista[i+1][j+1].visible=True
                if lista[i+1][j+1].val==0:
                    open_game(lista,lista[i+1][j+1])

        if j-1>=0:
            if lista[i+1][j-1].visible==False and lista[i+1][j-1].flag==False:
                lista[i+1][j-1].visible=True
                if lista[i+1][j-1].val==0:
                    open_game(lista,lista[i+1][j-1])


    if i-1>=0:
        if lista[i-1][j].visible==False and lista[i-1][j].flag==False:
            lista[i-1][j].visible=True
            if lista[i-1][j].val==0:
                open_game(lista,lista[i-1][j])

        if j+1 < len(lista):
            if lista[i-1][j+1].visible==False and lista[i+1][j+1].flag==False:
                lista[i+1][j+1]=True
                if lista[i+1][j+1].val==0:
                    open_game(lista,lista[i+1][j+1])

        if j-1 >=0:
            if lista[i-1][j-1].visible==False and lista[i-1][j-1].flag==False:
                lista[i-1][j-1]=True
                if lista[i-1][j-1].val==0:
                    open_game(lista,lista[i-1][j-1])


    if j-1 >=0:
        if lista[i1][j-1].visible==False and lista[i][j-1].flag==False:
            lista[i][j-1]=True
            if lista[i1][j-1].val==0:
                open_game(lista,lista[i][j-1])

    if j+1 < len(lista):
        if lista[i][j+1].visible==False and lista[i][j+1].flag==False:
            lista[i][j+1]=True
            if lista[i][j+1].val==0:
                open_game(lista,lista[i][j+1])


def game(size,bombas):

    #40x40 pixeles
    grey=pygame.image.load("grey.jpg")
    white=pygame.image.load("blanco.jpg")

    #20x20 pixeles
    cero=pygame.image.load("cero.png")
    uno=pygame.image.load("uno.jpg")
    dos=pygame.image.load("dos.jpg")
    tres=pygame.image.load("tres.jpg")
    cuatro=pygame.image.load("cuatro.png")
    cinco=pygame.image.load("cinco.jpg")
    seis=pygame.image.load("seis.png")
    siete=pygame.image.load("siete.png")
    ocho=pygame.image.load("ocho.png")
    nueve=pygame.image.load("nueve.png")
    bandera=pygame.image.load("bandera.jpg")

    numero=[cero,uno,dos,tres,cuatro,cinco,seis,siete,ocho,nueve]

    c=Board(minas(size,bombas))
    w=h=len(c.board)*40
    pantalla=pygame.display.set_mode(w,h)

    #crea una lista de los cuadros organizados

    lista=[[] for i in range(size)]
    for i in range(0,size*40,40):
        for j in range(0,size*40,40):
            lista[i//40]+=[Square(i,j,40,40,c.board,(i//40),(j//40))]
            screen.blit(grey,(i,j))


    run=True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                run=False
                pygame.quit()

            elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if evet.key==pygamee.K_r:
                    run=False
                    restart(size,bombas)

            elif event.type==pygmae.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button==1:
                #verificar con clic izquierdo
                for i in lista:
                    for j in i:
                        r=pygame.rect.Rect(pygame.mouse.get_pos(),(1,1))
                        if j.rect.colliderect(r):
                            if j.flag==False: #si esta con bandera
                                if j.val==9: #si es una bomba
                                    print("GAME OVER")
                                    run=False
                                j.visible=True
                                if j.val==0:
                                    j.visible=open_game(lista,j)
                                    j.visible=True

            elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and even.button==3:
                #si el jugdor presiono el clic derecho, se pondra o se quitara la bander
                for i in lista:
                    for j in i:
                        r=pygame.rect.Rect(pygame.mouse.get_pos(),(1,1))
                        if j.rect.colliderect(r):
                            if j.visible==False:
                                if j.flag==False:
                                    j.flag==True
                                elif j.visible==True:
                                    j.flag=True


        #ahora abriremos cada cuadro

        for i in lista:
            for j in i:
                if j.visible==True:
                    screen.blit(white,(j.x,j.y))
                    screen.blit(numero[j.val],(j.x+10,j.y+10))
                if j.flag==True:
                    screen.blit(flag,(j.x+10,j.y+10))
                if j.flag==False and j.visible==False:
                    screen.blit(grey,(j.x,j.y))

        cont=0
        for i in lista:
            for j in i:
                if j.visible==True and j.val !=9:
                    cont+=1
                    #cuenta los cuadro visibles
            if cont== size*size - bombas:
                run=False
                print("YOU WIN")
        pygame.display.update()

    #si ganamos o perdimos muestra los lugares de las bombas
    for i in lista:
        for j in i:
            if j.val==9:
                screen.blit(nine,(j.x+10,j.y+10))
    pygame.display.update()

    #espera por salida o reincio
    run=True

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                run=False
                pygame.quit()
            elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type==pygame.K_r:
                    run=False
                    restart(size,bombas)




print("presione 'r' para reinicio")
size=int(input("Ingrese tamaño de la matriz"))
bombas=int(input("Ingrese el numero de bombas"))
game(size,bombas)
```

presione 'r' para reinicio
Ingrese tamaño de la matriz10
Ingrese el numero de bombas5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\buscaminas.py", line 297, in <module>
    game(size,bombas)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\buscaminas.py", line 195, in game
    c=Board(minas(size,bombas))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
pygame.error: Couldn't open grey.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Board:
    def _init_(self,board):
        self.board=board
```

`__init__` requires two underscores on each side, for a total of four. Same for `__repr__`.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self,board):
        self.board=board
```